# Grid won't render on first page load (Netzke + Rails 4 + extjs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, ruby-on-rails-4, netzke

I experience a weird behavior using `netzke` + `rails 4` + `extjs-4.2.1`
Every time the page load at first time the div is displayed but the grid is not loaded until I refresh the page. I can't reproduce the error using `rails 3` + `netzke 0.8` + `extjs-4.1`. Could this be a netzke bug? I use the browser console and no error is displayed.

I'm currently using this version of netzke:

```
gem "netzke-core", "~> 0.10.0.rc2"
gem "netzke-basepack", "~> 0.10.0.rc2"
```

and `Rails 4.0.2` with `extjs-4.2.1`

My application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Railroad</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= load_netzke %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <h1>Demo</h1>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
                <%= link_to "Español", :locale=>'es'%>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "English", :locale=>'en'%>
            <%end%>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <%= link_to (t :sign_out), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My welcome/index.html.erb

```
<h2><%= t :post_option %></h2>
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to (t :post_list),  posts_path%></li>
    <li><%= link_to (t :post_new),   new_post_path%></li>
</ul>
```

My posts/index.html.erb

```
<h2>TEST</h2>
<%= netzke :posts, height: 400 %>

<br/>
<%=  link_to (t :back), root_path %>
```

My routes.rb

```
Railroad::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  netzke
  root "welcome#index"

end
```

My model post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

And my components/posts.rb

```
class Posts < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = "Post"
    c.columns = [
        :title,
        :text
    ]
    c.prohibit_update = true
    c.prohibit_delete = false
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update**

The problem appears to be related to `NetzkeController` when I click a `link_to` it send me to page with grid but the `NetzkeController` it's not executed using `0.10.0.rc2` as result the grid is not loaded until I refresh the page, but if I do the same scenario in 0.8 the `NetzkeController` it's called and loads the grid.

Here is the log file after the page is renderes for `netzke 0.8` and `0.10.0rc2`

0.8

```
Started GET "/test/view" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 09:07:48 -0600
Processing by TestController#view as HTML
  Rendered test/view.html.erb within layouts/application (19.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 41.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-03-19 09:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Started GET "/netzke/ext.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 09:07:48 -0600
Processing by NetzkeController#ext as CSS
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-03-19 09:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/netzke/ext.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 09:07:48 -0600
Processing by NetzkeController#ext as JS
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-03-19 09:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started POST "/netzke/direct/?authenticity_token=vkC6OERWwyDwHU5Hqnqpu%2BH83PNpqLnikPADBoZvrME%3D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-19 09:07:48 -0600
```

0.10.0rc2

```
Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 13:02:58 -0600
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i finally solve the problem specifying the method on all the links that render the page, it's weird because netzke 0.8.0 don't need this maybe this will be solved at the official release.

Here is my new application.html.erb, not the link_to on the locale.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Railroad</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= load_netzke %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <h1>Demo</h1>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
                <%= link_to "Español", {:locale=>'es'}, :method => :get%>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to "English", {:locale=>'en'}, :method => :get%>
            <%end%>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <%= link_to (t :sign_out), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my new welcome/index.html.erb

```
<h2><%= t :post_option %></h2>
<ul>
    <li><%= link_to (t :post_list),  posts_path, :method => :get%></li>
    <li><%= link_to (t :post_new),   new_post_path%></li>
</ul>
```